# Oracle to HBase data transfer tool?

Tags: oracle, hbase

Need to continuous sync-up data between Oracle (source of truth) to HBase, and wondering if any existing solutions?

thanks in advance,
Lin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at [Apache Sqoop](http://sqoop.apache.org/) a tool for efficiently transferring bulk data between Apache Hadoop and relational databases (like MySQL or Oracle). It supports [data import into HBase](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.2/SqoopUserGuide.html#_importing_data_into_hbase).